# ¿Cómo realizar un predicado en prolog que liste todos los grados de cada vértice de un grafo?

Tags: lista, prolog

primero encontramos el grado de un vértice específico.

```
%predicado_grado
%grado(+Vertice,+Grafo(Vertices,Aristas),-Grado)
%caso_base
grado(_,grafo(_,[]),0).

%caso_recursivo
grado(A,grafo(_,[arista(A,_)|Resto]),Grado):-
         %conectado(A,X,_),
         grado(A,grafo(_,Resto),Gr),
         Grado is Gr+1.  
         
grado(A,grafo(_,[arista(_,A)|Resto]),Grado):-
        %conectado(X,A,_),
         grado(A,grafo(_,Resto),Gr),
         Grado is Gr+1. 
     
grado(A,grafo(_,[arista(X,Y)|Resto]),Gr):-
         A\=X,A\=Y,
         grado(A,grafo(_,Resto),Gr).

%Ejecutar_en_prolog:         
%?- grafo1(G),grado(d,G,Gr).
```

eso en cuestión para obtener el grado de un solo borde o arista, pero no he podido listar todos los grados con sus respectivos valores de cada borde o arista.

```
% predicate_list_degrees
% de grado (Gráfico, Lista de grados).
```

Como resultado en prolog seria:

```
% GradeList = [(a, 2), (b, 2), (e, 2), (c, 2), (d, 4), (f, 1), (g, 1)].
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas este es la solución del predicado lista grados.

%predicado_lista_grados
%grado(+Grafo, -ListaGrados).
%ListaGrados=[(a,2),(b,2),(e,2),(c,2),(d,4),(f,1),(g,1)].

el caso base seria un +Grafo, -Lista de grados

```
%caso_base
grados(grafo([], _), []).

%caso_recursivo
grados(grafo([Ca| Resto], Aristas), LR):-
    %calcular_el_grado_del_vertice_de_la_cabeza
    grado(Ca, grafo(Vertices, Aristas), Grado),

    %agregar_los_grados_de_cada_vertice_en_una_lista_resultante
    grados(grafo(Resto, Aristas), LResto),

    append([(Ca, Grado)], LResto, LR). %juntamos la Cabeza, la lista Resto y la lista total
```

Se ejecuta en prolog con la siguiente linea:

% ?- grafo1(G),grados(G,ListaGrados).

Nota: esta solución fue dada por mi docente de la materia Sistemas Expertos.